# Reactjs, adding attributes to auto-generated classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, attributes, auto-generate

I'm trying to add an attribute to a generated react bootstrap class, but I can't figure out how.

```
<div>
    <div data-reactid=".1">
        <div class="modal-backdrop in" data-reactid=".1.0"></div>
        <div class="in modal" data-reactid=".1.1" style="display:block;" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" **add attribute here**></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

None of this is in my code. It's all generated in node_modules/react-bootstrap . Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to add?

Comment: an "id" attribute.

Comment: For what reason? You shouldn't need to be altering auto generated divs

Comment: It doesn't meet company standards. I'm guessing it isn't possible to add attributes without modifying the react library...